# What would happen if we do not write screen keyword in media query?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {

}
```

I learned that media type like `screen`, `print` etc. is used to instruct a browser that applies above media query to a particular type of media. But my prof. says we can also write it without a screen keyword. I asked him the reason but wasn't satisfied with it. My question is if it works without a screen keyword then how the browser will get to know whether the code is for print or for the screen?

Comment: It will use it for both.

Comment: This would be extremely simple to try out and observe the consequences.

Comment: Also, why didn't your professor's answer satisfy you? You're learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use the `not` or `only` operators, the media type is optional and the `all` type will be implied. Browser will apply that media query to both `screen` and `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: If you don't use the `screen` keyword, the browser *won't*  know whether you intend it for screen or print and will apply it to every media with that `max-width`.